# Show TableView in Swift Playgrounds for iPad

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift-playground

Everything works fine except the last line where I try to show the `tableView` in live view does not work: `PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = controller`

I can't figure out what I'm getting wrong?

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import Foundation

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let tableData = ["Matthew", "Mark", "Luke", "John"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("Hello Matt")
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableData.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
}

let controller = TableViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = controller
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Is there an error? What happens?

Comment: @JackLawrence akosma nailed it, appreciate you looking into it and checking what was wrong though

Comment: https://gist.github.com/watert/13c38d269ea15aa8360f

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you forgot to register the table view cell class in `viewDidLoad()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`, add one line to the top of the function:

```
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
    return cell

}
```