# How can custom tableview cells be made in swift playground?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In swift playground **(not in a project)** 
Could you please give me a hint about how to do this please?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WHHL.png)

Comment: have you tried importing UIKit and creating one programmatically?

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog yes i did it practically but was not able to do it

Comment: @Rob Thanks this is what i was looking for but what necessary changes can be done if label2 is not required?

Comment: @Rob 
 How can a standard cell be added in playground?

Comment: Then no subclassing of `UITableViewCell` is needed. Just use `UITableViewCell` directly, as shown in the second example of my revised answer below.

Answer (score 5):

You have to implement `init(style:reuseIdentifier:)` in your custom class to define subviews and constraints programmatically.

Thus:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var label1: UILabel!
    weak var label2: UILabel!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        let label1 = UILabel()
        label1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label1.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1)
        label1.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.572549045085907, green: 0.0, blue: 0.23137255012989, alpha: 1.0)
        label1.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        contentView.addSubview(label1)
        self.label1 = label1

        let label2 = UILabel()
        label2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label2.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1)
        label2.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.0901960805058479, green: 0.0, blue: 0.301960796117783, alpha: 1.0)
        label2.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        contentView.addSubview(label2)
        self.label2 = label2

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            label2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label1.trailingAnchor, constant: 10),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label2.trailingAnchor, constant: 10),
            label1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            label2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label1.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label2.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            label1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label2.widthAnchor)
            ])
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

And then you'd have a standard `UITableViewController` which registers this class and uses it:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    var objects: [String] = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
        return Array(0 ..< 1000).flatMap { formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: $0)) }
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")

        // set it up to let auto-layout resize the cell

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objects.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        cell.label1.text = objects[indexPath.row]
        cell.label2.text = "Row \(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Now that just creates a simple view like this:

[image]

That's not terribly pretty, but I set the background colors like I did, just so you can see that the frames are set appropriately. You'd obviously adjust your `init(style:reuseIdentifier:)` to create subviews more to your liking.

---

If you want the standard cell, then you don't need to have a custom cell subclass, but you can just use `UITableViewCell`:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    var objects: [String] = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
        return Array(0 ..< 1000).flatMap { formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: $0)) }
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objects.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = objects[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

On the iPad, that yields:

[image]

On Playground in Xcode, it yields:

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for but what necessary changes can be done if label2 is not required?

Comment: Rather than (sorry PETA) cutting the cat's tail off an inch at a time, why don't you tells us what you want in your custom cell? I.e., if you want only one label, why not use the standard cell?

Comment: How can a standard cell be added?

Comment: @GurpreetPaul For a standard cell have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39682759/3687801) question.

Comment: @Rob how were you able to get an _output_ screen like this btw?

Comment: @nayem - I did the above examples on my iPad's Playgrounds app, so I just did a normal screen capture. I.e., while holding the home button down, tap and release on the power button.

Comment: Ohh well I see. I thought you were on Xcode in mac. Is there any way to see the output without going into assistant editor in Xcode?

Comment: Ohh well I see. I thought you were on Xcode in mac. Is there any way to see the output without going into assistant editor in Xcode?

Comment: In Xcode's playgrounds, you use the assistant editor. The only exception is `CustomPlaygroundQuickLookable` views, which you can see in quick view right in the playground code, but that's not applicable here.

Comment: Try tapping over in the assistant editor window. I find that the Xcode Playground doesn't always update the assistant editor window, but by tapping in that assistant editor window can make it suddenly appear. Xcode playgrounds are a bit flaky.

Comment: @Rob but the code can be seen running through the little eye icon on the line of code on mac

Comment: @Rob but still can not be seen running in the assistant editor window

Comment: I don't know what else to suggest, as it works on my Xcode iOS playground. See Xcode 8.3 screen snapshot above. I got a similar result in Xcode 8.2.1 iOS playground.

Comment: @GurpreetPaul - I know this is going to sound crazy, but I'd suggest locating the "derived data folder" (which you can find via Xcode's "Preferences" - "Locations" and tapping the little arrow next to the "derived data" path), quit Xcode, delete what's in that derived data folder, reboot the Mac and try again. Sometimes when Xcode is misbehaving, the combination of emptying derived data and rebooting can help.

Comment: @Rob Thanks! worked when tried in a new playground after quitting xcode

Answer (score 1):

Full credit to @Rob, this is a tweak of his answer, but after trying to directly add the cell to a table view to no avail (cells seem to ignore explicit sizing), I reduced his view controller to a generic one for ease of re-use.

```
    class DashboardViewController<T: UITableViewCell>: UITableViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            tableView.register(T.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

            // set it up to let auto-layout resize the cell
            tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
            tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
        }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! T
            configure(cell)
            return cell
        }

        var configure: ((T) -> ())!

        static func with(configuration: ((T) -> ())!) {
            let controller = DashboardViewController<T>()
            controller.configure = configuration
            PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = controller
        }
    }

    // usage:
    DashboardViewController<MyCustomCell>.with() { cell in
        let model = MyCellModel()
        cell.model = model }
```